# Como fazer esta requisição

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

tenho este endepoint:

```
@GET("b1s/v1/ServiceCalls?\$filter")
@Headers("Prefer:odata.maxpagesize=1000")
fun getService(@Header("Cookie")token: String,
               @Query("TechnicianCode")TechnicianCode: Int,
               @Query("Status") codigo: Int): Call<ServicesValue>
```

estou usando o retrofit, desta forma a minha url esta ficando assim:

```
https://XXXXXXXXXX/b1s/v1/ServiceCalls?$filter=TechnicianCode = 201 & Status = -3
```

mas a api que estou fazendo a requisição do aceita desta forma:

```
https://XXXXXXXXX/b1s/v1/ServiceCalls?$filter=TechnicianCode eq 201 and Status eq -3
```

como consigo subtituir o sinal de *'='* por *'eq'*, porque o *@Query* adiciona *'='* automático?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o Retrofit não suporte tal configuração a cerca do caractere "=" do `@Query`, pois o mesmo representa um *query parameter* conforme a spec do HTTP. É por isso que o Retrofit adiciona o "=" automático, respondendo a tua pergunta.

O mais adequado, no seu caso, acredito ser criar um `@Query` com nome `$filter` e criar o valor que será passado ao parâmetro fora do Retrofit, numa implementação própria.

Exemplo:

```kotlin
@GET("b1s/v1/ServiceCalls")
@Headers("Prefer:odata.maxpagesize=1000")
fun getService(@Header("Cookie") token: String,
               @Query("$filter") filter: String): Call<ServicesValue>
```

```kotlin
fun makeFilter(technicianCode: Int, status: int) = 
    "TechnicianCode eq $technicianCode and Status eq $status"
```

Uso:

```kotlin
val filter = makeFilter(201, -3) // TechnicianCode eq 201 and Status eq -3
retrofitService.getService(token, filter)
```

Comment: Obrigado assim deu certo e esclareceu minhas duvidas.